# extJS didnt see too big text with many <br>'s

Tags: extjs

extJS didnt see too big text with many <\br>'s..

If i write `text` something like `"lalal lalalal lsadsdhas afjhjhj";` 
Its okei, works.

If i write `text` with \n (<\br>) something like:

```
"hello,

my name

is Polly!";
```

ExtJS didnt see those lines. How i can avoid this?

Thank you!

Comment: Read question by yourself again and then try to tell what you want...

Answer (score 0):

This is because Javascript doesn't allow multi-line strings. If you want a linebreak in your string, it has to be coded with an escape sequence like '\r\n'. So,

```
alert("hello, \r\nmy name\r\nis Polly!");
```

will display as 3 lines. If the string is going into an html element, then insert '<br />' in place of the '\r\n'.
finally, if you need a long string with lots of blank spaces between the words, for some reason, you can either keep typing on the same line, or break it up into several lines and combine the lines with the '+' operator, like this:

```
var longstring = 
'hello                                                       \r\n'
+'my name                                                    \r\n'
+'is Polly!';
```

Comment: thanks  for response, if i add a big, for example text with many <\br\s>, How i can get in extJS text with this \n's ? It is not possible?

Comment: @Jigo Soreenokoi, did you reread my answer? I added another example at the end.